# how to access Web sphere default messaging provide queues using HermesJMS?

Tags: jms, websphere-8, websphere-traditional, hermes-jms

Geetting error while trying to connect to websphere8 default messaging provider using following jars using hermesJMS

1. com.ibm.ws.orb_8.0.0.jar
2. com.ibm.was.sib.client.thin.jms_8.0.0.jar
3. com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.0.0.jar

> Error-
>   javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not stucked with HermesJMS, you could give a try to [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox) on sourceforge that allows to either connect directly to the internal WAS SIB or via a JMS Connection Factory
JMSToolBox is very easy to configure to connect to WAS SIB

Comment: Thanks, but I am using HermesJMS because it is bundled with SOAPUI and we can easily use its functionality in it.

Comment: Could you please suggest if there is way to integrate it with soapui?

Comment: Some features of JMSToolBox are exposed as REST services. Depending on your requirements, in SoapUI you can define REST requests to post/get messages from your MQ provider. Also, you can define scripts and templates that can contain variables (random of from list) and so generate some activity directly from JMSToolBox without SoapUI. Scripts in JTB can also read templates from a predefined directory etc. I still need to expose script via the REST interface...

Comment: JMSToolBox REST services documentation is [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmstoolbox/wiki/REST)